# PHP OOP not passing variables in the class

Tags: php, class, oop, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I have a PHP class that is meant to get a mysqli query, make a multidimensional array, and currently just echo the whole array. It is this code:

```
include("connect.php");

class database
{
    public $motto;
    public $motto_array = array();
    public $rating;
    public $rating_array = array();
    public $category;
    public $score;
    private $mysqli;
    public $counter_array = array();
    public $multi_dim_values = array();
    public $multi_dim_category = array();


    function setMysqli($mysqli)
    {
        $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    }

    function setCategory($category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    function query_category()
    {
        if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT motto, score FROM mottos WHERE category=? ORDER BY score DESC"))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $this->category);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($motto, $ranking);
            while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
                $this->motto_array[] = $motto;
                $this->rating_array[] = $ranking;
            }
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }

    function multi_dim_array()
    {
        $multi_dim_values = array($this->motto_array, $this->rating_array);
        $counter_array = range(0,count($this->motto_array)-1);
        foreach($counter_array as $index => $key) {
            $foreach_array = array();
            foreach($multi_dim_values as $value) {
                $foreach_array[] = $value[$index];
            }
            $multi_dim_category[$key]  = $foreach_array;
        }
        return $multi_dim_category;
    }


}

$class = new database;
$class->SetMysqli($mysqli);
$class->SetCategory("person");
$class->query_category();
print_r($class->multi_dim_array);
print_r($class->multi_dim_category);
```

connect.php has the database connection information for the mysqli.

I am learning OOP, so I did this in procedural, and it works fine, with this code:

```
include("connect.php");

    function category($mysqli, $cat)
    {
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT motto, score FROM mottos WHERE category=? ORDER BY score DESC"))
        {

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $cat);

        $stmt->execute();

        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
            printf ("[%s (%s) in %s] \n", $motto, $ranking, $category);
            $array .= compact("motto", "category", "ranking");
        }
        print_r($array);*/

        $a = array();
        $b = array();
        $c = array();
        $stmt->bind_result($motto, $ranking);
        while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
            $a[] = $motto;
            $b[] = $ranking;
        }
        $result = array();
        $values = array($a, $b);
        $c = range(0,count($a)-1);

        foreach($c as $index => $key) {
            $t = array();
            foreach($values as $value) {
                $t[] = $value[$index];
            }
            $result[$key]  = $t;
        }

        return $result;

        $stmt->close();

        }
    }
    $cat = "person";
    $array_one = category($mysqli, $cat);
    print_r($array_one);
```

This prints the multidimensional array just like I want it to.
What am I doing wrong in the OOP code?

Thank you.

Comment: What is happening in your OOP code? Do you get an error message? Is the output wrong? If so, in what way?

Comment: Yes, we need to see what happens when you instantiate it and call each method. Make sure each method returns TRUE/FALSE so you can debug it locally on a method-basis.

Comment: Going waaayyy off topic but... is it just me or should the acronyms PHP and OOP never go next to each other like that? Particularly when teamed up with the phrase "not passing"! I swear I'm old enough not to giggle at this, but still.

Comment: How would I go about making each method return TRUE/FALSE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
print_r($class->multi_dim_array);
```

You forgot the `()`, so you're not invoking the method. You're accessing a (non-existent) property. Try this:

```
print_r($class->multi_dim_array());
```